# Jquery counter with Commas

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, jquery-waypoints

I've been trying to get a counter working along with waypoints in an animation.

The jquery counter I use below works a charm with elements containing only numerals (i.e. 8000). However I've been asked to use a "," as a separator as in 8,000. This throws the script out. I've managed to use a function (commaSeparateNumber) to print a comma to the element when the counter is run (i.e. 8000 becomes 8,000), which is great except for when javascript is not available and the fall back remains without the ','.

Therefore I need some help in first removing the comma from the target element and then running the counter along with the current function that places it back into the element. This will cover me for any fallbacks.

Any ideas are appreciated. Code is below. Thanks!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('.Count').each(function () {

            $(this).waypoint(function () {
                var $this = $(this.element);
                jQuery({Counter: 0}).animate({Counter: $this.text()}, {
                    delay: 5000,
                    duration: 2000,
                    easing: 'swing',
                    step: function () {
                        $this.text(commaSeparateNumber(Math.ceil(this.Counter)));
                    }
                });

                function commaSeparateNumber(val) {
                    while (/(\d+)(\d{3})/.test(val.toString())) {
                        val = val.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d\d\d)+(?!\d))/g, "$1,");
                    };
                    return val;
                }
                this.destroy();
            }, {
                offset: '95%'
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: store the number in data attribute. Keeps text and display numbers separate

Answer (score 0):

I dunno what your code is exactly doing so I can only advise you on how to remove commas:

```
 var number = "8,000";
 number = parseInt(number.split(',').join(''),10);
```

**OR**

```
var number='8,000';
a=a.replace(/\,/g,'');
a=parseInt(a,10)
```

The above code will remove the commas.